# JSF project wiring

Tags: jsf

I am writing a simple enough program using JSF, and I need some advice about how to go about it. I have a jsp which takes a unique ID and has to find out if the ID exists in 3 different databases. If it does it should display a message telling user, where it exists, otherwise it should give the user option to add the ID to a particular database.

I have the jsp page which has a text field for the input ID and I have a button called "Submit" which should trigger the process of querying the db to see where the ID exists. My question is, how to structure this project, in terms of front end, middle teir and db layer.
I have a JSP page, when the user clicks the Submit button, I have a listener in the managed bean which gets executed.  I have also read up that the listeners can either be a managed bean or a separate class. Should  I have a separate class which is the listener? If so, should it be a Servlet mapping in the web.xml file, so all request get forwarded to this class. Should there then be a separate DAO class where the actual query 
gets executed. We are using hibernate as well.

I would jsut like to hear people comments about how many classes there should be and how a particular ID Check will flow through the program from JSP->Servlet(?)-> DAO and then back to the same jsp. There is only JSP , there will be no other navigation pages.

Any direction will be much appreciated.

---

I have used Spring in the past, and this would be a breeze fore me with Spring, using the Controllers to delegate the requests to the appropriate service, and then the service would call the DAO class. But here we are using JSF and it has to be a JSF web page. I have not used JSF before so I am unsure about the different components needed. I have the front end jsp and a DAO class with the actual query, just wondering about the  middle tier, with business logic. How does the front end request after clicking the Submit button get to the middle tier, what wiring is required? Is it in the web.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you take a good long look at [Spring](http://www.springsource.org) framework. Here's a [Spring MVC](http://static.springframework.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/) tutorial to get you started.